# First Law of Thermodynamics and friction

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, friction

I have a body on a horizontal surface with friction. My thermodynamics system is only the body and I want to describe this with the first law of Thermodynamics. Suppose the body has a start kinetic energy and for the friction in the final state it has no more kinetic energy. For this problem there isn't a heat exchange but only a work exchange caused from the friction.
How can i write the fist law with this system?

Comment: If a portion of kinetic energy is dissipated then heat is evolved and the remainder can stay kinetic or converted into other forms of work. This is energy conservation. Dissipation *is* heat, no need for heat exchange, instead it is generated or "evolved".

Answer (score 2):

From the first law of thermodynamics, $$\Delta U+\Delta (KE)+\Delta (PE)=Q-W$$The change in PE is zero, since there is no change in elevation.  Heat leaves the interface in an amount equal to the work done on the interface, so applying the 1st law to the interface, we have $$0=F d+Q_{interface}$$So, $$Q_{interface}=-F_{system\ on\ interface}d$$The heat leaving the interface is partitioned between the infinite surroundings and the small (finite) system. So the amount that ultimately ends up in the system is essentially zero.  So, for the system, $$\Delta U+\Delta (KE)=+F_{interface\ on\ system}d$$where $F_{interface_on_system}$ is negative.  In the end, the change in temperature of the system is zero (system and surroundings at equilibrium), so $\Delta U=0$, and we are left with $$\Delta (KE)=+F_{interface\ on\ system}d$$where the right hand side is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no heat exchange, First law of thermodynamics tells you $$\Delta U = W_{on}$$
Friction force will do work on the box,
$$W_{on} = \int \vec{F}_{fric} \cdot d\vec{s}$$
As friction always works opposite to displacement, this work would be negative. For a distance $s$ covered under constant friction force of magnitude f, $$W_{on} = -fs$$
Now the total energy of the system, U, consists of all the macroscopic and microscopic energies of the system. In this case, microscopic energies of the body (vibration of molecules, interactive energies of molecules, etc.) Doesn't change. So, the change in internal energy is just the change in kinetic energy,
$$\Delta U = \frac{1}{2} m (v_f^2 - v_i^2) = -\frac{1}{2} mv_i^2$$
Combining everything gives the expected result $$\frac{1}{2} mv_i^2 = fs$$

Comment: “Now the internal energy of the system U consists of all the macroscopic and mircoscopic energies of the system.”. The internal energy only consists of the microscopic energy of the system.

Comment: “Since there is no heat exchange” But there is heat exchange at the interface of the body and surface. It occurs as a consequence of the increase in temperature due to the friction work

Comment: 1. My bad. I was referring to the total energy of the system with U, not just the internal energy. Corrected. Thank you. 
2. I think the question said there is no heat exchange. So, I assumed that the body was made of an insulator or something.

Comment: 2. I believe when the OP said no heat exchanger it meant temperature increases are due to friction work and not due to heat